# Using Recursion to obtain elements from nested tuples of tuples in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to obtain elements from this nested tuple in Python.

```
def get_val(d):
  _, _, c, _d = d
  yield c
  yield from ([] if not isinstance(_d, tuple) else get_val(_d))
nested_tuple = (0.0, 0.0, (6, 6), (5.656854249492381, 0.0, (2, 2), (1.0, 0.0, (5, 6), (5.656854249492381, 0.0, (2, 2), (1.4142135623730951, 0.0, (5, 5), (5.656854249492381, 0.0, (2, 2), (2.23606797749979, 0.0, (4, 5), (5.656854249492381, 0.0, (2, 2), (2.8284271247461903, 0.0, (4, 4), (5.656854249492381, 0.0, (2, 2), (3.605551275463989, 0.0, (3, 4), (5.656854249492381, 0.0, (2, 2), (4.242640687119285, 0.0, (3, 3), (5.656854249492381, 0.0, (2, 2), (5.0, 0.0, (2, 3), (5.656854249492381, 0.0, (2, 2), (5.656854249492381, 0.0, (2, 2), None)))))))))))))))))
print(list(get_val(nested_tuple)))
```

Output:

```
[(6, 6), (2, 2), (5, 6), (2, 2), (5, 5), (2, 2), (4, 5), (2, 2), (4, 4), (2, 2), (3, 4), (2, 2), (3, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 2), (2, 2)]
```

But it is supposed to output:

```
[(6, 6), (5, 6), (5, 5), (4, 5), (4, 4), (3, 4), (3, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2)]
```

I have run out of ideas and am very stuck right now. The worst part is I can't find out why

Comment: So you want to extract the tuples of two elements?

Comment: Why do you expect every second nesting level to be skipped?

Comment: What is producing that monstrosity of a data structure, and what is it supposed to represent?

Comment: a* algorithm (x,y) position values from a start position to an end position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you wish to skip every other third-position value:

```
def get_val(d, count):
  _, _, c, _d = d
  if not count%2:
    yield c
  yield from ([] if not isinstance(_d, tuple) else get_val(_d, count+1))

nested_tuple = (0.0, 0.0, (6, 6), (5.656854249492381, 0.0, (2, 2), (1.0, 0.0, (5, 6), (5.656854249492381, 0.0, (2, 2), (1.4142135623730951, 0.0, (5, 5), (5.656854249492381, 0.0, (2, 2), (2.23606797749979, 0.0, (4, 5), (5.656854249492381, 0.0, (2, 2), (2.8284271247461903, 0.0, (4, 4), (5.656854249492381, 0.0, (2, 2), (3.605551275463989, 0.0, (3, 4), (5.656854249492381, 0.0, (2, 2), (4.242640687119285, 0.0, (3, 3), (5.656854249492381, 0.0, (2, 2), (5.0, 0.0, (2, 3), (5.656854249492381, 0.0, (2, 2), (5.656854249492381, 0.0, (2, 2), None)))))))))))))))))
new_result = list(get_val(nested_tuple, 0))
```

Output:

```
[(6, 6), (5, 6), (5, 5), (4, 5), (4, 4), (3, 4), (3, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: @EvanKim Glad to help!

Comment: @EvanKim are you sure that the final output should be [(6, 6), (5, 6), (5, 5), (4, 5), (4, 4), (3, 4), (3, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2)]? Because I noticed a pattern in the nested_tuple where you try to get all the values with the first variable of d to be bigger than 5, except the last one. it looks to me that you need to change the if correspondingly